# Update 6 text boxes with 1 slider by clicking on each box to chose which one to update

Tags: jquery, textbox, onclick, slider, return-value

I am trying to create a form with 6 text inputs in which their values is updated by a slider.

I dont have problem doing this however, I need to make each boxes to be active just when it is clicked deactivating the other ones and keep their values.

I have been trying to do it with this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
var box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
var box3 = document.getElementById("box3");
var box4 = document.getElementById("box4");
var box5 = document.getElementById("box5");    

    slider.onchange = function(){
    box.value = '1 = ' + slider.value;
}

$('#box1').click(function(){
  $(this).data('clicked', true);
});

if($('#box1').data('clicked')) {
    slider.onchange = function(){
    box1.value = '2 = ' + slider.value;
}
} else {
    box.value;
}

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j3hEV/2/

Any suggestions on how to do this?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

html

```
 <input type="text" id="box" data-clicked="1" value="1 = 0.00 " readonly><br>
 <input type="text" id="box1" data-clicked="2" value="2 = 0.00 +" readonly><br>
 <input type="text" id="box2" data-clicked="3" value="3 = 0.00 +" readonly><br>
 <input type="text" id="box3" data-clicked="4" value="4 = 0.00 +" readonly><br>
 <input type="text" id="box4" data-clicked="5" value="5 = 0.00 +" readonly><br>
 <input type="text" id="box5" data-clicked="6" value="6 = 0.00 +" readonly><br>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {           
  var slider = $("#slider"); 
  var boxes = $("[data-clicked]");     
  $(boxes).on("click", function(e) {
    $(boxes).removeClass("clicked");
    $(e.target).addClass("clicked");  
  });        
  $(slider).on("change", $(boxes), function(e) {         
    $(".clicked")
    .val( $(".clicked").data("clicked")+ " = " + $(slider).val() );
  });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/f86nQ/

Comment: I was wondering any idea on how I can add css toggle to it when clicked and remove it when another one is clicked?

Comment: @SalvoNostrato Not certain what "add css toggle" means. Please clarify ? The `clicked` `class` should exist only on `clicked` element. Can possibly add appropriate `css` to stylesheet with `.clicked {/* styles for "clicked" */}` ?

Comment: Sorry very bad explanation of my question, this is what I meant. http://jsfiddle.net/f86nQ/18/    - Thank you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f86nQ/19/ I caanot get around how to load the page with the first box on.

Comment: @SalvoNostrato Please clarify " I caanot get around how to load the page with the first box on" ? What does "on" mean within that context ? Also, please note `$('#boxon').unbid('change');` at http://jsfiddle.net/f86nQ/20/ Is that piece intended `.unbind()` ?

Comment: "On" = "active". I just want to get the first text-box active as soon as the page load, instead of clicking it to activate it. Sorry

Comment: @SalvoNostrato Try `$(boxes).eq(0)` for "first text-box", then, perhaps "chain" applicable methods ?

Comment: not working . Tried with  $(boxes).eq(0); but the first box is still locked on load

Comment: $(boxes).eq(0).focus() ? Directly following `$(boxes)` variable declaration. Not certain what "action" occurred at "selection" ?

Comment: $(boxes).eq(0).focus(); Using this is highlighting the text in the first box. Instead I need the that the slider is active and can change the value for the first box on load without click on it.

Comment: maybe something like this $(boxes).eq(0).val();

Comment: @SalvoNostrato Try `.focus()` both `boxes` and/then `slider` ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/salvonostrato/2Qsmf/   -- Doing like that the text and the handle of the slider get Highlighted.

Comment: That was it, thank you so much. Any advice where to look to learn more advanced jquery like this?

Comment: @SalvoNostrato Thanks ! See api.jquery.com

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to select the next box when submit is clicked instead of clicking on the box itself.

here the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/salvonostrato/hygc6/

Comment: @SalvoNostrato Should be possible, perhaps caching `.clicked` `index` for `event`s synchronization